# How can i add footer to .rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting

I have a .rdlc report and it has matrix. that matrix has some money per month.  for example

> ```
> SHOP  MAY      JUNE             JULY
>
> abc   1200         1210              1220
> def   300       400              500
> ```

that months creating dynamicly and i want to add sum per month like that:

> ```
>           1500        1610                  1720
> ```

I cant see "footer" because .rdlc is matrix. how can i add sub sum per month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add page footer, Look at the picture

[http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/7293/reportk.jpg http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/7293/reportk.jpg](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/7293/reportk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Refer This link.Here they showed with sample example.

[How TO Use Matrix](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56877/Create-Matrix-Report-using-ReportViewer-in-ASP-NET)